# splitting data into consecutive time intervals

Tags: r

I have for example this time series data (boston) where I want to estimate and plot the trend component, the seasonal component, and the remainder (residual component). I did it like this:

```
install.packages("fma")
library(fma) 
plot(stl(boston[,1], s.window = "per"))
plot(stl(boston[,2], s.window = "per"))
```

Now I would like to split the data into two consecutive time intervals, where the second interval should contain about 1/4 of "boston".

I would use the first interval to estimate a model, and the second interval  for prediction, which then can be compared to the data. For this I would like to visualize the first part of the time series with plot(), but enlarge the x-range in order to add a line for the second part later on. However, I am stuck here and don't know how to really proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(fma) 
index=0.75*nrow(boston)
train = boston[1:index, ]
test = boston[-(1:index),] 

> nrow(train)
[1] 26
> nrow(test)
[1] 9
```

Comment: thanks. When I write the last part (nrow(train)...) I get an error message "Error: unexpected numeric constant in "nrow(train) [1] 26""

Comment: @Jeff, what code do you exactly run?

Comment: I run your code after my code from above

Comment: @Jeff, That is weird. I don't get that error when running your code and my code. Could you please share the complete error?

Comment: my mistake. I made an error while entering the code. It works.

Comment: @Jeff, Great to hear!